# Missing ssh_config option and how to go about getting it

Tags: linux, ssh

I've got a number of linux servers in our data centre, most are Debian systems and few are Red Hat.  On the Red Hat systems I'd like to modify the ssh_config to change the default value of the option ExitOnForwardFailure.  Unfortunately this option doesn't seem to be valid on this server.

So, what I'm wondering is if it's possible to update ssh in such a way that I could gain access to the option.  It's important for me to be able to use the option to accomplish what I'm trying to do and I'm a little bit suprised that it's not there.  I've done some Googling and have seen many references to folks using this option on Red Hat.

Anyway, where might I start if I wanted to go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see that in the man page for ssh_config on my RHEL boxes.  But it shows up in the [man pages](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) for the latest release on the OpenSSH site.  Looking at their release notes, it appears this feature was added in [version 4.4](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-4.4).  The version of SSH that RHEL5 uses?  4.3.  Awesome.

Odds are, the people you've seen using this with RedHat are running Fedora, as opposed to RHEL or CentOS.  That's the consumer desktop variant, and is much more liberal with updating packages.  (a cynic might say 'current')  To get the latest version of SSH on a RHEL machine, you'll probably need to compile from source.


--Christopher Karel

Comment: Thanks Cristopher.  That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Quick clarification: When you say 'compile from source' do you mean OpenSSH source or the entire RedHat OS?

Comment: Just the OpenSSH binaries.  You can download the source code from www.openssh.com.